# Mysql записать всю выборку в переменную

Tags: mysql

Всем доброго времени суток задача такая:
Записать  результат select в переменную без придикатов

```
set @a  = ( select name from Faces limit 1); // так все работает 

set @a = ( select name from Faces ); //mysql #1242 - subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Ошибка понятна но как  тогда записать весь результат в  переменную.

Comment: дак может не стоит пытаться вписать в переменную типа Строка, или что там у вас, набор этих строк? временные таблицы вам в помощь

Comment: )))  окей понял.  с временными  таблицами понятно . но хотелось бы понять в таком случаи какой тип должен быть у переменной и как на это повлиять .